# Uploading file in remote Flask server instead of local one

Tags: web-services, flask, file-io, filesystems, flask-sqlalchemy

I would like to build a Flask web application that processes a CSV file. The documentation provides sample code for uploading a file to a Flask server and downloading it once the file is processed (for reference: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/patterns/fileuploads/). However, this requires a local path for file uploads. I am wondering how this works when the web app is deployed in the cloud (remote server). Where are the uploads stored? Furthermore, I would prefer not to use a database since the application only needs to process the uploaded CSV and output a file (it has no other functionality).

Can you please help me figure out how this works when the app is deployed? Is it possible to not use a database in this situation?

Thank you in advance!